# AngularJS $q promises not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

So it seems I still don't understand promises correctly.  Below is a controller which get an array of posts via a resource.  Its supposed to first get the array, then load the array into the scope as a separate function.  This isn't working because all the functions in the promise still seems to get called synchronously.  For example, the function called `getPosts()` takes over one second because I have inserted a delay on the server to simulate latency.  But despite taking over one second, all the other functions within the promise are called synchronously.  Any clues would be great.

```
var postController = myapp.controller('postController', function ($q, $rootScope, $scope, Post, $routeParams) {

    var new_posts = []

    $scope.new_post_count = 0

    var getPosts = function () {
        $scope.refreshing = true
        var params = $routeParams
        Post.query(params).
            $promise.then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.refreshing = false;
                new_posts = response
                $scope.new_post_count = new_posts.length - $scope.posts.length
            },
            function (response) {
                alert('Snap! ' + response.status)
            }
        )
    }

    $scope.refreshPosts = function () {
        $scope.posts = new_posts
        $scope.new_post_count = 0
    }

    /* all the functions below (marked 1, 2, 3) within the promise still called synchronously.
    I thought they would wait until the previous function has finished? */
    var defer = $q.defer()
    defer.promise
        .then(function () {
            // 1
            console.log('calling getposts')
            getPosts()
        })
        .then(function () {
            // 2
            console.log('calling refresh posts')
            $scope.refreshPosts()
        })
        .then(function () {
            // 3
            console.log('calling interval')
            $interval(function () {
                    getPosts()
                }, 7000, 0
            )
        })
    defer.resolve()
```

Comment: `all the functions in the promise still seems to get called synchronously.` What is `all the functions`? Thanks

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question.  I hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you call your `refreshPosts` inside the callback of `getPosts`. Like this:

```
var getPosts = function () {
        $scope.refreshing = true
        var params = $routeParams
        Post.query(params).
            $promise.then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.refreshing = false;
                new_posts = response
                $scope.new_post_count = new_posts.length - $scope.posts.length;
                $scope.refreshPosts();
            },
            function (response) {
                alert('Snap! ' + response.status)
            }
        )
    }
```

If you do need to call it using `.then` like in your code. You need to return a promise in your function

```
var getPosts = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $scope.refreshing = true;
        var params = $routeParams
        Post.query(params).
            $promise.then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.refreshing = false;
                new_posts = response
                $scope.new_post_count = new_posts.length - $scope.posts.length;

                deferred.resolve(response); //resolve deferred object 
            },
            function (response) {
                alert('Snap! ' + response.status);
                deferred.reject(response); //reject deferred object 
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise; //return a promise.
}
```

Then modify your promises chaining like this:

```
function Refresh(){
    var defer = $q.defer()
    defer.promise
        .then(getPosts) //modify it here
        .then(function () {
            // 2
            console.log('calling refresh posts')
            $scope.refreshPosts();
        })
        .then(function () {
            // 3
            console.log('calling interval')
            $interval(function () {
                    Refresh()
                }, 7000, 0
            )
        })
    defer.resolve();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `$timeout` returns promise as well we can simulate the flow. Further, take a look that in promise chain we return promise for the next `then(/*..*/)`:

```
 var defer = $q.defer()
    defer.promise.then(function () {            
            console.log('calling getposts');
           return  $scope.getPosts();
        })
        .then(function (result) {
           $scope.data = result.data.results[0];   
            console.log('calling refresh posts')
           
            return $timeout(function () {
                   console.log('refresh posts called');
                }, 3000)
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log('calling interval')
            $timeout(function () {
                  console.log('interval called')
                }, 3000)
        },
             function (result) {
                           alert("Error: No data returned");
                       }
              )

      defer.resolve();      
    
   $scope.getPosts = function () {   
      return Data.query($scope.url); 
    }
```

Please see the full Demo in <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/783/)**</kbd> and the console.

Hope it will help

### The reference:

**promise**

> A promise represents a future value, usually a future result
> of an asynchronous operation, and allows us to define what
> will happen once this value becomes available, or when an
> error occurs.

**promise chain**:

[image]

Comment: +1 The reference section is what helped me. I wasn't passing the returned data to the function(data) call within the first .then. ugh.